# Tortoise TTS: AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: pytorch

Im trying to run tortoise tts on my computer and getting this following error:

> raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
> AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

My computer doesn't support CUDA, I would like to use the CPU only version of pytorch. How can I resolve this error?

I have already modified some of the existing code and added: `map_location=torch.device('cpu')` to `torch.load` to make sure it is using the CPU version.